# How do I stop PulseAudio from creating so many [Peak Detect] channels in pipewire/qpwgraph? (Linux Mint)

Tags: linux-mint, audio, alsa, pipewire

So, for some reason there are these channels called "PulseAudio Volume Control [Peak Detect]" and they pop up multiple times when opening apps and anything else that uses audio output. It is **always** connected to "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo", which is the fallback input in my configuration. Regardless of the fallback device, Firefox will make multiple of these Peak Detect things and it will clutter up my qpwgraph. Audacity is the worst offender, every time I open the program it makes about 20 of them at once, which makes the program open slower.

[image: PulseAudio Volume Control Peak Detect]

There you can see how many of them are open. I disconnected all of them but there will always be one connected when something new is open. How do I stop these from popping up? They are slowing down qpwgraph and Audacity.

I should add that this is Linux Mint 21.1!

Comment: these don't exist on my Fedora, as far as I can tell. Are you perhaps using some software that does something with these Peak detections? Or maybe the software used to display these is just not great and instead of stopping to display destructed nodes, it just always adds new ones, but in reality at any given time, only one exists?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah I edited the post to include that this is on Linux Mint, probably important. The software that causes this seems to be limited to Firefox and Audacity. OBS is a program that also captures audio and runs playbacks but it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

`pulseaudio` does not create these devices by default but other programs like `pavucontrol` will (that's the one you are probably using (?))

I think `pavucontrol` is very useful but I did not find any other way to prevent the creation of these peaks monitors than actually slightly changing the code (not a really clean hack though) (would be much better to have a flag set as an optional argument probably)

Of course you still will be able to adjust levels but won't have any visual feedback (no peak meter)...

In `mainwindow.cc`:

```C
pa_stream* MainWindow::createMonitorStreamForSource(uint32_t source_idx, uint32_t stream_idx = -1, bool suspend = false) {
  return NULL; // will surely prevent the creation of a monitor...
```